# are attributes called multiple times at the conditon of for loops?

Tags: javascript, optimization

A programmer told me that when codding loops if an attribute is added at the conditional part, it is then calculated at each iteration.

Ex:

```
var elements=['a','b','c','d'] // imagine a very long list

for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) { // <- Here is array.length being called
    var element = elements[i]
}
```

In this case, if what he told me is true: `elements.length` would be called at each iteration in order to calculate the condition.

To optimize the code I'll then do:

```
var elements=['a','b','c','d'] // imagine a very long list
var elements_length=elements.length

for (var i=0; i < elements_length; i++) { // <- Here is array.length being called
    var element = elements[i]
}
```

And probably this can not even noticed with small lists.

Is all this true? Is there any way of checking this? Probably this can be checked with a timer, but I was wondering if this is a known behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it is true. The calculation will repeat itself at each iteration.

In the old days it made a big difference as you can see [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html#data_access_time_across_browsers). Nowadays the differences have become much smaller though.

It got me curious so I ran some tests. As it seems:

1. Chrome and Firefox (Latest versions) have almost no differences between the two methods.
2. In IE (8, 9, 10, 11, Edge) the differences are more noticeable (Also in Edge). Another interesting thing is that the loop takes much more time in IE compared to Chrome and Firefox.

**Average differences between the methods in IE:**

[image]

Keep in mind that the differences are **noticeable only for really big arrays**.

The best way is always to test for yourself. I add the basic code. Run it many times and calculate average for accurate results.

```js
// performance polyfill to support old browsers
(function () {

    if ("performance" in window == false) {
        window.performance = {};
    }

    Date.now = (Date.now || function () {  // thanks IE8
        return new Date().getTime();
    });

    if ("now" in window.performance == false) {
        var nowOffset = Date.now();
        if (performance.timing && performance.timing.navigationStart) {
            nowOffset = performance.timing.navigationStart
        }
        window.performance.now = function now() {
            return Date.now() - nowOffset;
        }
    }

})();

var elements = [];
var count = 0;
while (count < 10000000) {
    elements.push(count++);
}
arrlength = elements.length;

var t0 = performance.now();

// With .length
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i]
}

// With variable
//for (var i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
//    var element = elements[i]
//}

var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Took: " + (t1 - t0) + "msecs");
```

```html
See details in console
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true , but with very low performance gains. 
One optimization when using **for loops** is to assign the Length property of the Array in a Variable outside the Loop so that you avoid the engine calculating the Length of the Array in each and every iteration.

The performance gain is low though and will only be noticable in extremely large arrays.

It is a good practice though to always use it regardless of size just to be on the "safe" side.

Keep in mind that the JS engines are getting better and better as time passes , the compiler is making a lot better optimizations and some "practices" seize to exist. That means that if the assigning the Length property outside the loop is providing a small performance gain at this moment , soon this might not be true.
Check this out , it will provide a few info about your case : [Hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)

Answer (score -1):

Well this memoization of the array length in loops has always been recommended for the sake of performance. I believe it shouldn't be done really since the gain is very negligible compared to the risks it introduces. There is a caveat. If you morph your array during and throughout the loop (by inserting or deleting items) then your reference on the length will probably deceive you if you don't use the proper array length property in each round.

Ok here comes for the downvoter... As you see the following one with memoized length property will not be able to count all the way to the end if an item is added and will try excess counts and return non existent undefined items if an item is deleted.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5],
    l = a.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
i == 1 && a.splice(i,0,"test");
console.log(a[i]);
}
```

As you see this one works as expected when `a.length` is not memoized.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
i == 1 && a.splice(i,0,"test");
console.log(a[i]);
}
```

It's a good practice to use `array.length` in your loops directly.

Comment: `If you morph your array during and throughout the loop (by inserting or deleting items)` This is pointless. It's *never* a good idea to modify an *array* while iterating.